# SAS Proc SQL Macro variables in Where clause

Tags: sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I am trying to write a program in SAS using the Prompt manager variable within a `PROC SQL` statement. It isnt working for me and keeps saying that the symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Heres a sample of my code...

```
LIBNAME mylib ORACLE  SCHEMA = 'myschema'  PATH = prd  USER = 'admin'    PASSWORD = 'admin12';

PROC SQL;
   SELECT DISTINCT TEST_ID, COUNT(*), TERM                       
   FROM mylib.testtable 
   WHERE RELEASE = 'PRETEST' 
     AND TEST_ID IN (&TEST) /* 'MATH', 'READING', 'SCIENCE' */
     AND TERM = 'SPRING'  
   GROUP BY TEST_ID, TERM 
   ORDER BY TEST_ID, TERM;
QUIT;
```

And here is the problem in the log:

```
40          WHERE RELEASE = 'PRETEST'
41              AND TEST_ID IN (&TEST) /* 'MATH', 'READING', 'SCIENCE' */
NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "TEST".
41         'MATH', 'READING', 'SCIENCE'
       _
       22
        _
        200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
          a missing value, (, -, SELECT.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

My prompt variable is `&TEST` and should hold the list of tests to take but it dosent.

Comment: Can you double check that your column is a character column?

Comment: @RobertPenridge That would be a different error, methinks.

Comment: What kind of prompt did you define?  Can you explain exactly what steps you took to define the prompt?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is one related to macro quoting.  It's apparent that the token is enclosed in macro quotes (similar to `%nrstr` basically) for some reason, which cause it to work slightly differently than a normal `%let`.  `%unquote` fixes it.  I suspect there is also a better way to define the prompt to cause this not to occur, but I'm not completely sure - maybe one of the more experienced EG 
folks can answer.

(Define a TEXT - SINGLE VALUE prompt called `type` and attach it to a program containing this:)

```
proc sql;
  select name, age
    from sashelp.class;
    where name in (%unquote(&type.))
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution to my dilemma. As Joe stated, its a macro quoting issue, but it was also an array issue too. Both are solved by wrapping the variable in double quotes and some rudimentary replication.

Long story short, 
the way SAS handles arrays and multiple values caused the first value to show only the first value so I had to assign multiple nullable values.

Working product below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   TEST_ID, COUNT(*),  TERM
FROM mylib.&TABLE 

WHERE RELEASE IN ("&RELEASE", "&RELEASE1", "&RELEASE2", "&RELEASE3") 
  AND TEST_ID IN ("&TEST", "&TEST1", "&TEST2", "&TEST3", "&TEST4", "&TEST5") 
  AND TERM IN ("&TERM", "&TERM1", "&TERM2", "&TERM3", "&TERM4") 

GROUP BY TEST_ID, TERM
ORDER BY TEST_ID, TERM;
```

Adding the &Release, &Release1, ect. allows multiple values to be captured should there be an array of values, otherwise it would accept the first value default the 
extra values to null and throw a warning.

This was sufficient enough to be able to provide a list of options to the user and allow them to run using one or more parameter in each field

Comment: AND TEST_ID IN ("&TEST")  <== so the solution is this?

Comment: The answer if yes IF: you pass one argument OR if you want the FIRST value in a passed array